# Update all rows with one SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I'm using this PostgreSQL table to store configuration variables:

```
CREATE TABLE SYS_PARAM(
 SETTING_KEY TEXT NOT NULL,
 VALUE_TYPE TEXT,
 VALUE TEXT
)
;
```

[image]

How I can update all configuration settings values using one SQL statement?

Comment: Just use a separate update for each parameter.

Comment: Yes but the effort is to reduce the number of the SQL queries. What if I have hundreds of lines? I can't easily maintain so much queries.

Comment: Unless you are solving a specific performance problem, trying update multiple rows in an EAV data model is premature optimization.  You can wrap the updates in a transaction, so they all take place at one time.  Changing such settings should be a rare even so even if running a few hundred queries takes a few hundred milliseconds, then that should have negligible impact on overall performance.

Comment: Can you show me example of one transaction please?

Comment: IMHO the current table lacks a key element; it allows only one configuration to be stored. So this is not an EAV model but a AV model, which is rather useless, unless used as a template for instantiating other configurations. Which would need the extra key element, too.

Comment: Should I use integer key or I should make SETTING_KEY primary key?

Comment: At first glance, it appears SETTING_KEY should at least have a unique constraint; however, as wildplasser mentioned, there may be more you need to evaluate with this design.

Comment: What do you mean by `need to evaluate with this design`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov - have you read wildplasser's comment? Do you understand it - if not, you could ask and/or research it. You need to at least appear to put in as much effort in finding your solution as the others on this site are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on performing these updates more than once or twice over time, it would be good to have a function handle this for you. You could use the table itself as a type for a variadic parameter within a function, like so:

```
-- The function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sys_param(VARIADIC params sys_param[])
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN

  UPDATE sys_param
    SET value_type = upd.value_type, value = upd.value
  FROM
    sys_param src
  INNER JOIN
    UNNEST(params) upd
    ON  (src.setting_key = upd.setting_key);

END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

-- To call it
SELECT update_sys_param(('SMTP_PORT','int','123'),('SMTP_OTHER','text','435343'));
```

However, if this is a one-time update you can try either of these two:

**UPDATE using JOIN**

```
UPDATE sys_param
   SET
     value_type = new.value_type,
     value = new.value
FROM
   sys_param src
INNER JOIN
   new_params new --< this table/view/cte must already exist or you must create it.
   ON  (src.setting_key = new.setting_key);
```

**UPDATE using CASE**

```
UPDATE sys_param
SET value = CASE setting_key
      WHEN 'SMTP_PORT' THEN '2100'
      (..and so on..)
      END;
-- You would need to repeat the case statement if you intend on updating the value_type, too.
```

Comment: For the example with `UPDATE using CASE` how I can also update column 'value_type'? (just in case for a specific case)

Comment: @PeterPenzov You need to add a similar case statement. The concept is the same. I hesitate to do all the work for you :-). Please give it a try on your own - you should have enough information to do so. That is the best way to learn.

Comment: @PeterPenzov - If you are still having problems after trying it on your own, feel free to let me know and I will be happy to walk you through it.

Comment: @PeterPenzov - That is because your `value` field is TEXT and you are providing (some) non-TEXT data type (INT, in this case). You should make sure you pass them using the proper data type (TEXT / String).

Comment: Yes, I found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you can use `where true` at the end and it update all rows in your table.
for example:

```
UPDATE table_name set table_column = value where true;
```

it will be update all rows in one SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve this by doing correlated update.

Please refer to the posts below:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/sqlp/rbafyexsub4.htm

Comment: Can you give some example, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov - The link shankarsh15 provided contains 2 examples. The thing is, you need to have another table with the new values you want to update your source table to. That would take just as much, if not more work than just updating the source table directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can join against a list of values and update with that:

```
update sys_param
   set value = v.new_value
from (
  values 
     ('SMTP_PORT', '123'), 
     ('SMTP_SERVER', 'new_server'),
     ('SMTP_USERNAME', 'Arthur')
) as v(skey, new_value)
where v.skey = sys_param.setting_key;
```

This assumes that `setting_key` is the primary key of that table.